# How set dynamically windows back ground image in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, desktop-application

I have small doubt in wpf,i kept image on button.so when we click on button that image should be set as back ground?what should i do? any one have idea>
please let me know.

Thanks in Adavance
Developer

Comment: If you do not express yourself more clearly about what you have (possibly provide code) and what you want it is difficult to help.

Comment: An image on a button is fine, no special action required.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to put an image as a background of any control (button or grid, didn't understancd you), just set, in code, the Background property to an ImageBrush with an ImageSource of your image.

Answer (score 0):

This code is for button, edit it ...

```
Button button = new Button();
button.Margin = new Thickness(220, -880, 0, 0);
button.Width = w;
button.Height = h;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
ImageBrush berriesBrush = new ImageBrush();
berriesBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Image/country.PNG", UriKind.Relative));
button.Background = berriesBrush;
button.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
```

This might you ...